# How can I access a user defined configuration set in the pom.xml file, in the angularjs app.js file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maven

So I'm new to  maven, angular and javascript for that matter I've been put on a project with all three of them.

So my question is, how can I set a property in the pom.xml file and reference it in an angular file like app.js. 
In the back end I piped them through the config.properties file. Like so

pom.xml

```
<google.maps.api>API_STRING</google.maps.api>
```

config.properties

```
google.maps.api=${google.maps.api}
```

.java file

```
String property = Config.getProperty("google.maps.api")
```

How can I pipe this through to the front, in particular app.js in angular to specify an API like so:

```
uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        key: // Something like config.getProperty("google.maps.api")
});
```

I'm not sure how to reference the property from the front end / angular.

Can someone help plz?

Comment: Same way as you'd access any other back-end value.

Comment: So in app.js you would write key: configure.getProperty("google.maps.api")? 
Cause I've tried that

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: There are any number of mechanisms you can use; you could pass it in an Ajax call, create a dynamically-generated JS file with server-side values in it, etc.

Comment: Hi, so I've created a dynamically generated js file with all the config and environment variables from config.properties with a gulp module, but the enviroment variables didn't compile, so essentially I'm getting a the actual string value I pass in. 

So console.log(config['mapsApi']) returns ${google.maps.api} and not my actual api.

Cute, but no good. 

Do you know of a gulp plugin off the top of you head that can compile these environment variables?

Comment: No. I'm not sure I understand, though; you can't magically access server-side variables from JS--if you're pre-building JS then you should be building the JS in a way that actually includes the values, not reference Java artifacts.

Comment: Hi Dave, 
Thanks for the feedback, I found three solutions. 
One was to get the variables in config propereties from java, referencing and resolving them with a Config.getProperty() function and then writing them to a seperate file, and referencing that file from js. That didn't work because I was working in google app engine that restricts the use of file output streams.  

But Then I discovered gulp! And so I figured out that you could use a maven command to resolve your references to a seperate file and then use a gulp task to convert that into a json and reference that. 

Thanks though